# How to check contours whether they are ellipse or not by using fitEllipse function in OpenCv C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, ellipse

```
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    findContours(img, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
```

*Now how can i get the location of ellipses from these contours??*

Comment: fitEllipse will not tell you, if the contour was an ellipse or not.

Comment: so how can i find the ellipse by using these contours??

Comment: fitEllipse fits the best ellipse to the contour, but it will find the best fitting ellipse for a square, a triangle a duck or any other contour it gets. do you want to evaluate whether the contour is an ellipse or not, or find the best ellipse that describes the contour

Comment: Yes i want to know which one is ellipse or not..So kindly tell me how can i get to know about ellipse..

Comment: you can use `minAreaRect` http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#minarearect for each contour. Then reinterpret those rotated rectangle axes to be ellipse axes instead and compare the difference between that ellipse and the contour (or the difference between fitEllipse and the minAreaRect-Ellipse)

Comment: the other (probably better) way to do it would be to create a RANSAC ellipse detection and test it on each contour, but afaik there is no such method built in openCV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to for each contour:

- calculate the ellipse (using fitEllipse function)
- draw filled contour and (on other mat) draw the filled ellipse (from previous point)
- substract (or - probably better - use absdiff function) on mat from another
- find number of non-black pixels (use countNonZero function)
- if number of non zero pixels divided by contour area is small than this contour is ellipse, if this number is big - it's not an ellipse. You need to find values on you own

Drawing contours might be a little tricky, becuse it's hard to tell where to draw them. For me the best option is to find center of mass of contour and draw contour in such a position that center of mass will be in the same point as ellipse center.

Hope it helps and that it's clear, if not - let me know, i will try to explain it better.